# strptime tm_gmtoff is always zero

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

void main () {
        struct tm tm;
        memset (&tm, '\0', sizeof(tm));
        if (!strptime ("15/Sep/2014:16:00:00 +0300", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S%t%z", &tm)) {
                perror("strptime");
                return;
        }

        time_t gmt = timegm (&tm); // or mktime(), not relevant here
        printf("%d gmtoff=%lu %s %lu\n", tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_gmtoff, tm.tm_zone, gmt);

}
```

Result:

```
16 gmtoff=0 GMT 1410796800
```

I expected gmtoff to be 3.

It's like strptime is somehow parsing the offset, because it succeeds, but it does not fill the  offset in the struct. I've tried any kind of variant of that format string and datetime string without luck.

According to http://lxr.devzen.net/source/xref/glibc/time/strptime_l.c#751 the struct field should be modified.

Comment: What is the value of `tm.tm_gmtoff` *before* the call to `timegm()`?

Comment: You're using `memset` to initialize a data structure that contains arbitrary data. While the character literal `'\0'` should be equivalent to the integer value `0` (after conversion), I think it's wiser and clearer to use the actual integer value `0` instead of a character literal.

Comment: @unwind 10800, good catch... so I should use mktime(), I incorrectly assumed tm wasn't touched by timegm. Now I have to understand why mktime() leaks in my program, while using timegm() does not.

Comment: @lethalman Always be scared when calling functions accepting non-`const` pointers to stuff.

Comment: @unwind Want to turn that into an answer? :)

Comment: @unwind It's been a while, so I'm assuming you didn't, and did it myself. Feel free to post your own; I'll take mine down if you do.

Answer (score 0):

> According to http://lxr.devzen.net/source/xref/glibc/time/strptime_l.c#751 the struct field should be modified.

It is. In fact, it's modified *twice*. Nice! To demonstrate this to yourself, you can add this line just before the one with `timegm`:

```
printf("%lu\n", tm.tm_gmtoff);
```

You'll notice that the bit after `gmtoff` is different before and after the `timegm` line. `timegm` is modifying the struct you pass in. Before it's called, you're getting the values you expect; afterwards, you're... not.

Now, none of the documentation that I could find says anything about this particular feature. Things like that are why I'd prefer to use standard functions like `mktime`; it's a little bit more code, but what each function does is specified very well.

Comment: Yes, I realize this question is old. That's part of the point of this answer; I strongly dislike old, on-topic, unanswered questions.